# Will main thread call static block in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, block, program-entry-point

Will main thread call static block? Or how main thread used to execute before jdk7, where program used to execute without main method too?

in java main thread calls main method and execution starts, my question is, if we don't write main method and just write static block in a class (as we can do this in jdk6) in this case will main thread call static block?

Comment: A static block is not _called_, especially not from any method you write. The main method was the main entry point from the very beginning of Java!

Answer (score 1):

> Will main thread call static block in java?

You cannot call a `static` block in Java.

What you can do is trigger a class to be initialised which in turn calls the static block for you.

> Or how main thread used to execute before jdk7

This behaviour hasn't changed since Java 1.0

> where program used to execute without main method too?

When you try to start a program, it first loads the class, calling the `static` block even if you don't have a main method.  While this is interesting, I highly recommend you don't actually do this.